# hr content shows question mark

Tags: html, css

```
hr.style-eight:after {
    content: "§";
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative; 
    top: -0.7em;  
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: 0 0.25em;
    background: white;
}
```

but instead of it showing `§` it is showing `�`

any idea why?

Thanks

Comment: This seems like it's an issue with the typeface not including that specific character

Comment: Or an encoding issue... are you using utf8 wherever you can ?

Comment: @greg0ire `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probable explanation is that although the HTML document is *declared* to be UTF-8 encoded, it actually isn’t. It might be windows-1252 encoded, and when the windows-1252 encoded representation of “§” is encountered when processing presumed UTF-8 data, it constitutes a character data error. A common, and recommended, way in which browsers indicate the error is “�” REPLACEMENT CHARACTER.

To fix this, make sure the declared and actual character encoding match. It is less relevant which encoding you use, but other things being equal, it is best to use UTF-8. So you would need an editor or other authoring tool that can actually save the data as UTF-8 encoded.

If you absolutely cannot fix the encoding issue, replace `"§"` in CSS by the escape notation `"\A7"`. Much less readable, but works no matter what the encoding is.

General advice on the topic: the W3C page [Character encodings](http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset).

Comment: Thanks, adding it was just something to add to make the site looks fancy. I will just use `\A7` instead. Thanks again